# English and French reading rules

Tags: pronunciation, reading

Lieutenant is a word of French origin, and it is read as /le**f**ˈtenənt/.

I've never learnt French and I don't know anything about French reading rules, unfortunately. But I guess the English reading is related to the original French one.

Why is "lieutenant" read as /le**f**ˈtenənt/ when there is no **f** in the word?

Comment: In AmE, it's loo-tenant.

Comment: There is no /f/, written or pronounced, in *lieutenant* in French, and there never has been. Colin's answer seems to indicate that the /w/ sound at the end of a word was pronounced a little bit like /v/ in Old French, but I don't believe it ever was actually a /v/.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yeah, I know. In British English, it's /lefˈtenənt/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody is sure.

/lefˈtenənt/ is indeed the British English pronunciation of *lieutenant*, but not in American English.

The OED says:

> The origin of the β type of forms (which survives in the usual British
>   pronunciation, though the spelling represents the α type) is difficult
>   to explain. The hypothesis of a mere misinterpretation of the graphic
>   form (*u* read as *v* ), at first sight plausible, does not accord with
>   the facts. In view of the rare Old French form *luef* for *lieu* (with
>   which compare especially the 15th cent. Scots forms *luf-* , *lufftenand*
>   above) it seems likely that the labial glide at the end of Old French
>   *lieu* as the first element of a compound was sometimes apprehended by
>   English-speakers as a *v* or *f*.

Comment: Does that mean that French people pronounced /w/ a little like /v/ in Old French? (Like Hindu and Cockney in Dickens' time.) Is there any other evidence for this?

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't think it does mean that. It refers to a "labial glide" (which I interpret as /w/) and suggests that it was **English speakers** who misheard this as a fricative.